# Edit a specific cell in JTable on enter key and show the cursor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keylistener, tablecelleditor

I have added a keylistner to  JTable on frame.
Now on kepressed i have the code

```
            if (ke.getKeyCode()==10)
            {
              int rowIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
              int colIndex = jTable2.getSelectedColumn();
              jTable2.editCellAt(rowIndex, colIndex);
              ke.consume();
```

this does edit the cell  but the cursor is not shown till i click on it by mouse

Comment: Why?  Editing is controlled by the `TabelModel#isEditable` and `TableCellEditor#isCellEditable`

Answer (score 5):

Do not use a KeyListener!

Swing was designed to use Key Bindings (see the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)). That is you bind an Action to a KeyStroke.

By default:

1. The `Enter` key will move the cell selection to the next row
2. The `F2` key will place a cell in edit mode

So you want to replace the default Action of the Enter key with the Action of the F2 key. This is easily done by using Key Bindings:

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
KeyStroke f2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0);
im.put(enter, im.get(f2));
```

Also, check out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for a list of the default bindings for all Swing components.

Answer (score 0):

Try add Robot for F2 keyPressed:

```
if (ke.getKeyCode()==10)
    {
        int rowIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();
        int colIndex = jTable2.getSelectedColumn();
        jTable2.editCellAt(rowIndex, colIndex);
        ke.consume();

        Robot pressF2 = null;
        try {
            pressF2 = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        pressF2.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F2);
    }
```

I hope this work.